# How to make HTTP call to pod running in Docker Desktop (Kubernetes)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

So I am having an issue where I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when I try to make a call from my frontend which is setup as an Ingress. My backend express server is running on port 5000 and is setup as ClusterIP. I've read the docker for mac local cluster ip is the same as localhost so thats how I have it set.

I am confident I have the files and networking correctly. I am just not sure where to aim the API call to the backend. Is it also localhost? I will include the files below.

Frontend deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend-container
        image: mrich6347/vue-frontend:5
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "32Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Frontend service

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: frontend-service
    spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      selector:
        app: frontend
      ports:
      - port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
```

Express server deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: express-server-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: express-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: express-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: express-server
        image: mrich6347/express-server:5
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "32Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

Express server service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: express-server-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: express-server
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
```

Here is my api call from vue

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  created: async () => {
    console.log("SERVER IS UP")
    let res = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/test");
    console.log(res)
  }
}
```

And finally my simple express API

```
const app = require('express')();
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.send("WORKING!")
})


app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server is up on 5000")
})
```

Ingress Controller

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traffic-router
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /


spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend-service
              servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: Hi, you must replace `127.0.0.1` with your express server service name. I.E. `express-server-service` in your api call.

Comment: What address do you use to access your frontend service in the browser?

Comment: Also cluster IP's are not available via the macos localhost, the service needs to be exposed like your ingress (probably a LoadBalancer?)

Comment: @Matt the frontend is working. I am able to visit the frontend at localhost. But when I try making a call to my backend service which has cluster IP.. I get errors. I will try load balancer. Should it be a load balancer once it is put into production as well?

Comment: @matt Normally I would send all http access via an ingress controller rather than setting up a LoadBalancer on every service. but yes using a LoadBalancer to expose a service outside the cluster is pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read the docker for mac local cluster ip is the same as localhost so thats how I have it set

Services inside Docker for Mac Kubernetes are not directly available to your desktop. There are many Cluster IP's and only one `localhost` so if they were all exposed you would run into port conflicts on localhost pretty quickly.

Docker for Mac will automagically expose services with type [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#using-kubectl) on `localhost`. The concept is similar to running `docker run -p 80:30843 ...`. See the `EXTERNAL-IP` on this ingress controller.

```
$ kubectl get service m-nginx-nginx-ingress-controller
NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
m-nginx-nginx-ingress-controller   LoadBalancer   10.108.201.47   localhost     80:30843/TCP,443:31419/TCP   22h
```

```
$ curl http://localhost:80
default backend - 404
```

As it sounds like you already have an ingress controller for your front end service, it's easiest to reuse that ingress and map another host name or URI path through to your backend service.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. However, what If I am not wanting somebody to have direct access to the backend service. They should only be able to hit endpoints if it is coming through the frontend. Wouldnt seeting up another URI path or hostname defeat that?

Comment: If your vue browser app is making calls the the backend api, which your example codes implies, then the backend has to be accessible to the client

Comment: Also, I now have the backend using LoadBalacer and it says external ip is localhost with the port as 5000:30782/TCP. Does that mean I should be able to make request from my frontend like this https://localhost:5000/test?

Comment: Yep, again I would normally send the backend via the existing ingress service but it should work for now.

Comment: Oh I apologize, I didn't realize I hadnt put the ingress controller code in the question. I just added it to the original question at the bottom. Doesn't that looks right? I should be able to to hit the ingress which goes through the frontend service to my backend. However, it still gives me connection errors when trying to hit my backend which exposed via clusterIP.

Comment: Oh I see. So your frontend service already knows how to forward onto the backend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193800/discussion-between-matt-and-matt).